# Toggle Web Sharing

Tags: applescript

I'm looking for an Applescript to toggle Web Sharing in Snow Leopard. [I tried this](http://brenthardinge.net/comment/reply/380) but it doesn't disable, just restarts it when I run it again. Or a shell command as long as I can turn it into a Quicksilver action. That's my end goal. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following shell script to toggle the enabled state of a Mac OS X service:

```
#!/bin/sh
# toggle OS X service

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]
then
    echo 1>&2 Usage: `basename $0` service
    echo 1>&2 Toggle the enabled state of the given service.
    exit 2
fi

SERVICE_NAME=$1
SERVICE_PLIST=/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/$SERVICE_NAME.plist

if [ ! -f "$SERVICE_PLIST" ]
then
    echo 1>&2 Service $SERVICE_NAME is not available.
    exit 1
fi

/sbin/service --test-if-configured-on "$SERVICE_NAME"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    /bin/launchctl unload -w "$SERVICE_PLIST"
else
    /bin/launchctl load -w "$SERVICE_PLIST"
fi
```

The script uses the [service](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/service/) command to determine if the service is on and then toggles its state by invoking [launchctl](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/launchctl/).

The name of the service has to passed as the only argument. To toggle web sharing run:

```
sudo toggle_service.sh org.apache.httpd
```

To invoke the shell script via AppleScript you can use the [do shell script](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command:

```
do shell script "toggle_service.sh org.apache.httpd" password "pwd" with administrator privileges
```

Use the `password` parameter to avoid being prompted.

Comment: Is there a way I can save my password in the applescript so I don't have to enter it in the command? I want to use this with Quicksilver and set a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: So I tried to compile this and I got this: http://cl.ly/2LJH -> http://cl.ly/2Lgv -> http://cl.ly/2LlE

Comment: You are missing the "do shell script" part. Copy the command exactly as it is shown in code section.